# Como adicionar o efeito fadeIn neste código de transição de imagens

Tags: jquery

Queria saber como eu posso adicionar o efeito `.fadeIn(500)` nesse sistema que troca o `background` de 10 em 10 segundos.

```
<script>
    inicial_background = 0;
    function mudar_background(){
        img = new Array();
        img[0] = "style/img/bg_1.jpg";
        img[1] = "style/img/bg_2.jpg";
        document.body.background=img[inicial_background];
        inicial_background++;
        if (inicial_background==img.length){ 
            inicial_background = 0; 
        }
        setTimeout("mudar_background()",10000);
    }
</script>

<body onload="mudar_background();"></body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar CSS para fazer a transição...

Adicione `transition: background-image 500ms;` no seu ficheiro CSS.
É melhor adicionar no ficheiro CSS do que adicionar regras de CSS via javascript.

Se no seu caso é o `<body>` que muda o background pode usar:

```
.body{
    transition: background-image 500ms;
}
```

Comment: Bhá que bala, nem tinha pensado nisso =D

Comment: Mas o IE não pega o transition só o IE10 +

Comment: @Josimara, sim, só para IE10+. Mas as percentagens de utilização de IEs anteriores é muito muito pequena e vai diminuir: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: Tomara mesmo, é um sonho para muitos, mas um sonho muito maior é um fim para o IE hueheueh

Answer (score 1):

Tenta usar o plugin Jquery Backstratch....é bem simples e faz isso de modo responsivo...

http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

pra usar é assim, você faz o download do plugin que é um arquivo pequeno js, manda pro servidor e configura ele aqui

```
<script src="jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.backstretch([
      "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/outside.jpg" 
    , "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg"
    , "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/cheers.jpg"
  ], {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
</script>
```

Comment: Vou analisar o plugin

Comment: Mas ainda ta valendo se alguem tiver uma solução de como usar lá